# set the asp:textbox val() in jQuery and get the Text of the same on the server side code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have successfully set the text of asp:textbox using jQuery val() function, now I want the same value of the textbox on click of asp:button on the server side code.

```
$("#textboxId").val('some text');
```

```csharp
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // getTheText is blank
    string getTheText = textboxId.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: Make sure value of textbox is not being set on `Page_Load` on server side. If yes then out a check `if(!IsPostback)`

Comment: Is the text box within the form you're submitting?

Comment: Do you have any ajax panel?

Comment: check if your check textbox is enabled or editable? if not then it will cause an issue

Comment: I have not used any ajax panel, yes the textbox is enabled though out the scenario. The value of the textbox which is been set using jQuery is visible on the browser but as I said, not able to get it using Text property on button click()

Comment: my suggestion is to use input with runat="server". then check it on server side

Answer (score 3):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val("my value"); 

    });
</script>
```

and in code behind on button click use

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

this will work. it work for me i test it.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and finally found a solution.

```
string getheText =Page.Request.Form["textboxId"].ToString().Trim();
```

But be careful if you use "Content" in master page the id must be like that

```
string gettheText = Page.Request.Form["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$textboxId"].ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

if your textbox is an aspx server control then you can directly set Text by using

```
textboxId.Text = "Some Value";
```